# React-Native: Is it possible to scroll multiline TextInput when editable={false}

Tags: react-native, textinput

I have a form with multiline `TeaxtInput` field.

```
 <TextInput
     multiline={true}
     editable={false}
     numberOfLines={5}
 />
```

When the form is approved, all fields are not editable. But the problem is unable to scroll multiline `TextInput` field since it is not editable. User faces difficulties to read the complete text in the `TextInput`.

Hence, Is there any way to scroll multiline `TextInput` when `editable={false}`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe issue is in your other design code because TextInput is scrollable when `editable = {false}`, I've tried this and its working.

Comment: May I know what do you mean by `issue is in your other design code`? Can you please share your working code snippet?

Comment: It may your parent view or component of TextInput. [example here](https://snack.expo.dev/@wmt_rn_asmeetarathod/textinputeditablefalse)

Comment: 1. There is no parent view. `TextInput` is the only component returned form `render`. 2. You code is only working in `web` version, But not working when I selected `Android`.

Comment: Okay, it's my bad! You can refer this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23117#issuecomment-456702379)